# spring cloud config server don't use profile

Tags: spring, cloud, config, profile

I use:

```
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Brixton.SR6</version>
```

in my application.properties I have put

```
spring.profiles.active= prod
spring.application.name= FunctionalControl
```

I can see on the log :

```
2016-10-20 17:58:17.900 INFO  c.o.l.f.Application - The following profiles are active: prod
```

But if I use tcpdump I can see than despite does a GET /FunctionalControl/**prod** 
on my spring.cloud.config server It does GET /FunctionalControl/**default**

```
0x0030:  15f1 ddb3 4745 5420 2f46 756e 6374 696f  ....GET./Functio
0x0040:  6e61 6c43 6f6e 7472 6f6c 2f64 6566 6175  nalControl/defau
0x0050:  6c74 2048 5454 502f 312e 310d 0a41 6363  lt.HTTP/1.1..Acc
0x0060:  6570 743a 2061 7070 6c69 6361 7469 6f6e  ept:.application
0x0070:  2f6a 736f 6e2c 2061 7070 6c69 6361 7469  /json,.applicati
0x0080:  6f6e 2f2a 2b6a 736f 6e0d 0a55 7365 722d  on/*+json..User-
```

So I never manage to use FunctionalControl-prod.properties from my git repo :-(

Answer (score 2):

I found myself the solution and share it with everybody.

The active profile for config server is taken in consideration only if it is put into bootstrap.properties (or .yaml) not in application.properties

file bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active= prod
spring.application.name= FunctionalControl
```

I add this file in my project and then it works fine as you can see on this tcpdump

```
0x0000:  4500 00d3 0799 4000 4006 348a 7f00 0001  E.....@.@.4.....
0x0010:  7f00 0001 9f40 22b8 8800 ede0 32d2 4aa8  .....@".....2.J.
0x0020:  8018 0156 fec7 0000 0101 080a 16da ea48  ...V...........H
0x0030:  16da ea48 4745 5420 2f46 756e 6374 696f  ...HGET./Functio
0x0040:  6e61 6c43 6f6e 7472 6f6c 2f70 726f 6420  nalControl/prod.
0x0050:  4854 5450 2f31 2e31 0d0a 4163 6365 7074  HTTP/1.1..Accept
0x0060:  3a20 6170 706c 6963 6174 696f 6e2f 6a73  :.application/js
0x0070:  6f6e 2c20 6170 706c 6963 6174 696f 6e2f  on,.application/
0x0080:  2a2b 6a73 6f6e 0d0a 5573 6572 2d41 6765  *+json..User-Age
0x0090:  6e74 3a20 4a61 7661 2f31 2e38 2e30 5f34  nt:.Java/1.8.0_4
0x00a0:  350d 0a48 6f73 743a 206c 6f63 616c 686f  5..Host:.localho
0x00b0:  7374 3a38 3838 380d 0a43 6f6e 6e65 6374  st:8888..Connect
0x00c0:  696f 6e3a 206b 6565 702d 616c 6976 650d  ion:.keep-alive.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the active profile for your config **client** application (in your case "FunctionalControl"). There are multiple ways to do that.

E.g. you can add the following to your client's `bootstrap.properties` file

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

or e.g. start you config client application via

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

Either way, your client **server** application doesn't need any active profile. It will server whatever file is available in your git repo.